# Selenium not finding information(worked before)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have this script to get the bids of an NFT as they come in, It worked perfectly before however all of a sudden it stopped being able to find the information that i needed.
It was able to save the information into a file and then post the message onto discord
however now it cant get there due to it not being able to get the information.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import asyncio,calendar,discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "token here"
url = "https://auction.chimpers.xyz/"
class_names = ["m-bid-amount","m-bid-bidder","m-bid-timestamp","m-countdown-pending","m-name",'img']

bot = bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

channel_id = channel_id here

async def message_on_bid(auction_status="New Bid Placed",bid="has recieved a bid of",bought="from"):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    with open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","r") as f:
        info = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
        if len(info[1]) > 10:
            info[1] = info[1][:-(len(info[1])-4):] + "..." + info[1][len(info[1])-4::]
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title=auction_status,url="https://auction.chimpers.xyz/",description=f"{info[4]} {bid} Ξ{info[0][:-4]} {bought} {info[1]}",color=0x202020)
        myEmbed.set_footer(text=f"{info[2]}")
        myEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=info[5])

    await channel.send(embed=myEmbed)

async def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time > 60:
            await message_on_bid(auction_status="Auction Closed",bid="has been bought for",bought="by")
            print("auction closed")
            with open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","w") as f:
                f.write("0 ETH\nOwner\nTime\nAuctionStatus\nName\nimage")
                f.close()
            break
        driver_options = Options()
        driver_options.add_argument("--headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("Drivers\Chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get(url)

        results = {}
        try:
            for class_name in class_names:
                if class_name != "img":
                    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
                    # Getting inner text of the html tag
                    results[class_name] = element.get_attribute("textContent")
                else:
                    element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,class_name)))
                    results[class_name] = element.get_attribute("src")
        finally:
            driver.quit()

        print(results)
        this_list = []
        f = open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","r")
        for line in f.readlines():
            this_list.append(line.rstrip())

        if results["m-name"] == "Unnamed":
            results["m-name"] = this_list[4]

        if float(results["m-bid-amount"][:-4:]) > float(this_list[0][:-4:]):
            if results["m-countdown-pending"] == " Auction ended ":
                status = "AuctionEnded"
            else:
                status = "CurrentTopBidder"
            f = open("CurrentTopBidder.txt","w")
            f.write(str(results["m-bid-amount"]) + "\n" + str(results["m-bid-bidder"] + "\n" + str(results["m-bid-timestamp"]) + "\n" + str(status) + "\n" + str(results["m-name"]) + "\n" + results["img"]))
            f.close()
            await message_on_bid()
        else:
            f.close()

        driver.quit()
        await asyncio.sleep(600)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.loop.create_task(main())
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

any reason as to why this stopped being able to find the information????

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPOS0.png)

Comment: Error seems to be a timeout... but you may also want to switch to get_property instead of get_attribute... (textContent is a property...) get_attribute was never quite right, and I think Chrome/Chromedriver fixed it in more recent builds... OR just use the .text method.

Comment: _timeout_ is definitely from _`presence_of_element_located()`_ where as imo _`get_attribute("textContent")`_ is just fine.